# Passing data to autopopulate fields on an external website

Tags: php

I am creating a game comparison website and part of the process will allow the customer to complete their personal details (name, address etc..) on our comparison site and when they select their favourite 'buyer' they will be redirected to the external website of that buyer to complete the transaction.

I am trying to think of the best method that will enable me to 'auto-populate' the core fields that the external site will need such as 'firstname, surname, address1, address2, city, postcode, email address, home telephone number, mobile'

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this? As these will be totally external sites I won't be able to populate the fields simply using sessions - I can only think of using some form of querystring at the moment as the only option unless someone can think of a better method?

Comment: Use links like www.othersite.com/page.php?firstname=this&surname=that...?

Comment: Yeh - I was thinking that too.. I think as this will be used with multiple sites the easiest method to implement is the best so it will probably be the method you've described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the basic `$_GET` query string is the only way to go :-)